# Content-Disposition descarga los archivos, pero no abren

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario en el cual se puede crear un archivo, con opciones de nombre del archivo, contenido y qué tipo de archivo es. Después está la opcion de descargar el archivo que hayas creado.

```html
<h1>Generar documentos</h1>
<form action="generar_documento.php" method="post">
    <label for="document_name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="document_name" name="document_name" required>
    <br>
    <label for="document_content">Contenido:</label>
    <textarea id="document_content" name="document_content" rows="5" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <label for="format">Seleccionar Formato:</label>
    <select id="format" name="format">
        <option value="txt">Text (TXT)</option>
        <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
        <option value="jpg">JPG Imagen</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Crear y Descargar</button>
</form>
```

En un archivo *php* tengo mi código donde, depende del formato de archivo que se escoja, se crea y se descarga. Para descargarlo usé `content-disposition` que en el archivo de texto me funciona bien, pero en el **pdf** y **jpg** (aunque si los descarga) al momento de querer abrirlos no deja; me dice que el archivo no es compatible o que esta dañado y no sé por qué.

```php
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $documentName = $_POST["document_name"];
        $documentContent = $_POST["document_content"];
        $format = $_POST["format"];
        
        switch ($format) {
            case "txt":
                header("Content-Type: text/plain");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$documentName.txt");
                echo $documentContent;
                break;
            case "pdf":
                header("Content-Type: application/octec-stream");
                $pdf = new TCPDF();
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
                $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $documentContent, 0, 1, 'C');
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$documentName.pdf");
                break;
            case "jpg":
                $width = 400;
                $height = 200;
                $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
                imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
                $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
                $text = "$documentContent";
                $font = "arial.ttf"; 
                imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 50, 100, $black, $font, $text);
                header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$documentName.jpg"); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte de PDF y JPG faltan [enviar algunos headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652219/1545868) para que funcione.

Para el caso específico de la librería TCPDF, esta puede enviar el archivo generado directamente a la salida http con el método [Output()](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_Output).
Asegúrate de haber instalado correctamente la librería:
`composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf`
Y haberla agregado al script:
`require_once('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');`

En el caso del JPG asegúrate que esté encontrando la fuente (Arial.ttf). Coloca la ruta absoluta hacia el archivo de la fuente, o copia la fuente junto al script php. Si no encuentra la fuente generará un archivo corrupto.

Las librerías de PhpOffice no son necesarias para estos 3 casos, pero las dejé por si vas a generar más tipos de archivo.

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory; // <- *
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings; // <- *

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $documentName = $_POST["document_name"];
    $documentContent = $_POST["document_content"];
    $format = $_POST["format"];
    
    switch ($format) {
        case "txt":
            header("Content-Type: text/plain");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$documentName.txt");
            echo $documentContent;
            break;
        case "pdf":
            $pdf = new TCPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
            $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $documentContent, 0, 1, 'C');
            $pdf->Output("{$documentName}.pdf", 'D');
            break;
        case "jpg":
            $width = 400;
            $height = 200;
            $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
            $text = "$documentContent";
            $font = "C:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf";
            imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 50, 100, $black, $font, $text);
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$documentName}.jpg");
            imagejpeg($image);
            imagedestroy($image);
            break;
    }
}
?>
```